# How can I order files when adding them to zip by using jszip node js

Tags: node.js, zip, nest, jszip

Actually I am adding an array of files to a zip by using jszip package. the package adds my files based on date so I want to see my first element of array as the first file in zip but the package add one by one based on date and my first element goes to last and last element of array comes to first position.

I loop my array and want to add items one by one to zip file. without ordering them by date.

Comment: Can you share example code on how you are looping it

Comment: qrCodes.qrCodes.map((qrCode) => {
      zip.file(
        `${qrCodes.tagsInfo[qrCode].tagId}_${qrCodes.tagsInfo[qrCode].tagCode}.svg`,
        `${qrCode}`
      );
    });

Comment: @Kartoos thanks for your response. I loop a list of svgs as qrCodes and adding to file as above.

Comment: please edit the question and add the relevant code in the question itself instead of comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to try out the code and it is working fine...
Here is the code:

```js
var JSZip = require("jszip");
var fs = require("fs");
var zip = new JSZip();

const qrCodes = {
    qrCodes: [
        "b",
        "a",
        "c"
    ],
    tagsInfo: {
        "a": {
            tagId: "a_id",
            tagCode: "a_code"
        },
        "b": {
            tagId: "b_id",
            tagCode: "b_code"
        },
        "c": {
            tagId: "c_id",
            tagCode: "c_code"
        }
    }
}

// looping the array
qrCodes.qrCodes.map((qrCode) => {
    zip.file( `${qrCodes.tagsInfo[qrCode].tagId}_${qrCodes.tagsInfo[qrCode].tagCode}.svg`, `${qrCode}` );
});

// saving the zip file
zip
.generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.zip'))
.on('finish', function () {
    // JSZip generates a readable stream with a "end" event,
    // but is piped here in a writable stream which emits a "finish" event.
    console.log("out.zip written.");
});
```

I am on macOS so I have used `zipinfo` tool to check the order:

```bash
NodeJSTest % zipinfo out.zip 
Archive:  out.zip
Zip file size: 391 bytes, number of entries: 3
-rw----     2.0 fat        1 bl stor 22-Nov-22 07:47 b_id_b_code.svg
-rw----     2.0 fat        1 bl stor 22-Nov-22 07:47 a_id_a_code.svg
-rw----     2.0 fat        1 bl stor 22-Nov-22 07:47 c_id_c_code.svg
3 files, 3 bytes uncompressed, 3 bytes compressed:  0.0%
```

Although if I extract directly in Finder, it sorts it via Name, but still the contents of zip itself (without extracting) is ordered correctly!
If you are on windows, you can check the order by opening zip in say `7zip` and check the order without extracting it...